# How to shift a tikzpicture by the units displayed at axis?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use `tikzpicture` to create several diagrams which should be comparable at y-axis. I used `xshift` to shift one to the right by some arbitrary amount (10cm trial and error). But my `yshift` has to be excatly "2 units on the y-axis". I guess the default is pt, thus `yshift=2` is not working.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xmin=0,xmax=15,ymin=0,ymax=15, extra y ticks={2},]
        \addplot+[no marks,domain=4:10,samples=200, thick, blue] {0.3*(x-10)^2+4};  
        \addplot+[no marks,domain=0:11,samples=200, thick, blue] {2}; 
        \coordinate (X1) at (11,2);
  \end{axis}

  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xmin=0,xmax=15,ymin=0,ymax=13,xshift=10cm,yshift=2]
    \coordinate (X2) at (0,0);
    \end{axis}

    \draw[draw=gray, thick, dashed] (X1) -- (X2);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

15 on the left y-axis should perfectly equal 12 in the right diagram.

[image]

In addition here is some economic application from Baldwin/Wyplosz (2009): the right diagram always has to start at some constant value of the left diagram (here MC).
[image]

Comment: Maybe I do not understand the question: the two y axis have different scale (the left one spans 15 units, the right one 13) so they can't be "comparable" just by shifting...

Comment: The right diagram should start "at 2" in comparison to the left diagram. Overall they need to have the same size per unit. It is supposed to be shifted by that amount.

Comment: @KJO you see that I set it equal to 13 in the code. However, in default display options 12 is the last value/tick shown. I'm sorry for that issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `calc` to measure the shift.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xmin=0,xmax=15,ymin=0,ymax=15, extra y ticks={2},]
        \addplot+[no marks,domain=4:10,samples=200, thick, blue] {0.3*(x-10)^2+4};  
        \addplot+[no marks,domain=0:11,samples=200, thick, blue] {2}; 
        \coordinate (X0) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (X1) at (11,2);
        \path let \p1=($(X1)-(X0)$) in \pgfextra{\xdef\myyshift{\y1}};
  \end{axis}

  \begin{axis}[axis lines=middle,xmin=0,xmax=15,ymin=0,ymax=13,xshift=10cm,
  yshift=\myyshift]
    \coordinate (X2) at (0,0);
    \end{axis}

    \draw[draw=gray, thick, dashed] (X1) -- (X2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You could also use

```
 \path let \p1=($(0,2)-(0,0)$) in \pgfextra{\xdef\myyshift{\y1}};
```